# How to use an integer id to identify a class in a class hierarchy automatically?

Tags: c++, templates

For example, I have a base class `A` and its sub-classes `B`, `C` and so on. `B` and `C` can also has its sub-classes. The structure is a tree with root `A`. And each class in the tree is assigned a different integer to identify itself. There is no restriction on the integer id's values and orders. Just make sure they are different for different classes.

My question is how to do it smartly (or automatically) by using like template techniques since manual assignment is error-prone. Any way to get the id is fine, like

```
class A
{
public:
    static const id = ...;
};
```

or

```
template<class A>
struct Id
{
    enum { value = ... };
};
```

Comment: Could you specify better what you are looking to do with this code?  Generating integers at runtime is easier than generating integers at compile time which is easier than generating integers in time for use in switch statements.  Which case are you trying to use?

Comment: I use the id to do I/O and may have no good way from my undestanding of Cornstalks explanation.

Comment: So the id's have to be stable between builds of your code? i.e A always gets the value of 5?

Comment: Yes. It has to be stable.

Comment: There is no way to get a stable integer like that between builds.  I had to write similar code.  The solution was to give each class a UUID (written into the code manually... no automation).  UUIDs were deisgned to support cases like this.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is just a function

```
int nextId() {
    static int rval = 1;
    return rval++;
}

class A { public: static const id = nextId();  };
class B { public: static const id = nextId();  };
class C { public: static const id = nextId();  };
```

That will work so long as you do not need to use the IDs in dynamic initialization at the start of the program.

Edit: if that is not sufficient, the next step up is to do the same thing with static variables in a template.  This works across compilation units, but is still dynamic initialization time.

```
template <typename DummyT = void>
struct CommonCounter
{
    public:
        static int nextId() {
            static int rval = 1;
            return rval ++;
        }
};

template <typename T>
struct IdFor
{
    static int value()
    {
        static int rval = CommonCounter<>::nextId();
        return rval;
    }
};

class A { public: static const id = IdFor<A>::get(); };
```

Comment: Good idea. I'm not very sure if the compiler will call the function at compiler time. I just tested it. Seems it doesn't. Other ways?

Comment: Your question didn't mention that it had to be at compiler time.  What are the requirements on your id?

Comment: This will be problematic if the `id`s are in different translation units (assuming you want the `id`s to be consistent, as initialization order across translation units is not defined). Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: @Cornstalks Yes. It means if I write ids to file and open it by another version of executible (compiled by other compiler), the results may be wrong. Right? Any better way?

Comment: @user1899020: Yes, that is correct. I don't know what way might be best, as I've never found a need for giving each class an ID number.

Comment: You probably mean `IdFor<A>::value()` (not `get`). And I fail to understand how templates help here. Initialization order across TU boundaries is still not guaranteed, and all instantiations of the class template member function `IdFor::value` use the same type `CommonCounter<>`'s static member function.

Comment: Nice idea, but unfortunately, not legal. A static data member that is to be initialized within the class definition must be `const`, and even then, its initialization must be a constant expression. [class.static.data]/3 "If a non-volatile `const static` data member is of integral or enumeration type, its declaration in the class
definition can specify a *brace-or-equal-initializer* in which every *initializer-clause* that is an *assignment-expression* is a constant expression." (You could, however, use that technique to initialize the (const) static data members outside the class definition.)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this. This should give the same order on the same compiler. You could also modify how you key things to get a known order and detect problems at initialisation time. Simple implementation, not tested.

```
#include <typeinfo>

class A {
public:
    virtual ~A();
    static void register_type(std::type_info const& t);
    int id() const;
};

template<class T>
struct DoInitA
{
    DoInitA() { A::register_type(typeid(T)); }
};

class B : public A
{
    static DoInitA<B> s_a_init;
public:
    ~B() { }
};

//
// Implementation file.
//

#include <vector>
#include <functional>

namespace {
    struct TypeinfoLess {
        typedef std::reference_wrapper<const std::type_info> value_type;

        bool operator()(value_type const& lhs, value_type const& rhs) const {
            return lhs.get().before(rhs.get());
        }
    };
}

typedef std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<const std::type_info>> TypeVector;

static TypeVector s_types;
static bool s_init_complete = false;

A::~A() { }

void A::register_type(std::type_info const& t)
{
    static int s_counter = 0;
    if (s_init_complete)
        throw std::runtime_error("Late initialisation");

    s_types.push_back(std::reference_wrapper<const std::type_info>(t));
}

int A::id() const
{
    if (!s_init_complete) {
        sort(s_types.begin(), s_types.end(), TypeinfoLess());
        s_init_complete = true;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < s_types.size(); ++i)
        if (s_types[i].get() == typeid(*this)) return i;

    throw std::runtime_error("Uninitialised type");
}
```

Comment: `std::reference_wrapper<const std::type_info>(t)` can't this be simplified by `std::cref(t)`?

Comment: Oh, and btw, as `reference_wrapper` is C++11, you could just use [`std::type_index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index).

Comment: You could as well use a `std::set` instead of the `std::vector`, which also simplifies lookup. (Even with the `std::vector`, you could use a `std::binary_search`.)

Comment: @DyP: Well, std::binary_search is probably less useful than std::lower_bound, but yes, you could do that. For a small number of classes you don't care, for a big number you do. Either of these are probably preferable to std::set.

Comment: @DyP: On std::type_index. Yes, that is probably a nicer approach.